# Date becomes incorrect in the ALL view on Highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

When I use Highstock chart, with a lot of data, and the xAxis is dates, and set the view to ALL, all the dates seem to be off by 1 day.

I know this becuase  I have a handler that when I click on a point it shows the date. In the large view the date is off by 1, but in the smaller views, such as "1D" or "1m" views, (day/month), the dates are correct again.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  related with enabled dataGrouping, so I advice to disable it. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping